# How to "port" a large config file to an automated telnet script?

Tags: bash, automation, telnet

Im trying to make a script to automatically put the configs in to factory default Dlink 3200 switches. (ssh is no option it's disabled by default)
After trying with the"expect" function I switched to "echo" because I couldn't get expect to work.

I can now automatically log in:

```
(
  echo open 10.90.90.90
  sleep 2
  echo "admin"
  sleep 1
  echo "admin"
  sleep 1
) | telnet
```

But here is my problem; the config file that needs to be included is 900 lines long, so I am looking for a way to execute the commands in the config file, without having to copy/paste echo & sleep for each line...

Do you guys know a way to help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Michel

Comment: Please show us how you execute the code/config file. Perhaps a demo would do.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(
  echo open 10.90.90.90
  sleep 2
  echo "admin"
  sleep 1
  echo "admin"
  sleep 1
  cat config_file | while IFS='' read line
    do
      echo "$line"
      sleep 0.1
    done
) | telnet
```

Comment: use ``done < config_file`` instead. And what is the point of ``IFS=''`` ? Also it may be a good idea to use ``-r`` flag with ``read``.

Comment: `IFS=''` makes the `read` read also spaces and stuff without stripping them:  `echo "  bla" | { read a; echo "$a"; }` ⇒ leading spaces gone. `echo "  bla" | { IFS='' read a; echo "$a"; }` ⇒ leading spaces intact.

Comment: If you care about not having the `cat` process, then use redirection of input, yup.  Less readable, though (I find).